# Firebase Swift .exist() not working

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I am using firebase on swift and having an issue with .exist()

I am trying to do a query and check for a value, if its there I do nothing, if it isn't I add it to the list. I am just trying to avoid duplicating data this way. Heres the code:

```
InfoCenter.ref.child("users/\(InfoCenter.userId)/following").queryOrderedByValue()
    .queryEqualToValue(firstTextField.text)
    .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists(){
           self.displayAlert("You already follow that person!", Title: "Whoops")
           print(snapshot.value!)
        } else {
           InfoCenter.ref.child("users/\(InfoCenter.userId)/following").childByAutoId().setValue(TheId)
           InfoCenter.ref.child("users/\(TheId)/followers").childByAutoId().setValue(InfoCenter.userId)
           print(snapshot.value!)
        }
 })
```

so to me everything looks right, but when it runs snapshot.exist() always returns false but when I print snapshot.value! I get null with arrows around it (I couldn't type the arrows because SO thought it was a tag then) . So I'm confused.. how is null considered exists? Can someone please show me what to change to fix this? Thanks!!

Edit:
To be clear following is a list of users. So with in following are autoId's that have links to other users. The whole purpose of the above query is to go through the autoId's and make sure that this person does not already follow that person. Here is a snapshot of the data structure I am trying to explain:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I suggest an alternative? This solution reads the value as the location in question. Big benefit here is that there's no query overhead.

Assume we want to see if we follow frank and if not, follow him.

```
let ref = InfoCenter.ref.child("users/\(InfoCenter.userId)/following")
ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

     if let person = snapshot.value as? String {
        if person == "frank" {
          print("you are following frank: creeeeepy")
        } else {
          print("you are not following frank, follow him")
        }
      } else {
         print("node doesnt exist")
      }
})
```

this will directly read the value at

```
users/some_user_id/following: "the value that's read (frank in this case)"
```

Edit: based on an updated question, the 'following' node should look like

```
users
  your_uid
    following
      some_user_you_are_following_uid:  true
      another_user_you_are_following_uid:  true
```

then you are simply checking to see if the path exists

```
let ref = InfoCenter.ref.child("users/\(InfoCenter.userId)/following")
let theUserRef = ref.child("some_user_you_are_following_uid")
theUserRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
```

Comment: I think this only reads one value, I want to check all of the autoId's in following. Please see my edit to the question

Comment: @TNeate Yes, you are correct, it only reads one value. But that's what you are trying to do, right? The dynamic of your question changed so I added a bit to my answer but the concept still works...

Comment: awesome thanks! you're right my data structure was setup incorrect

Answer (score 0):

I think your query might not be be working user `InfoCenter.userId` might be an optional force unwrap and see if that return the snapshot.

Comment: No sorry thats not it, I've checked the url and its good. InfoCenter.userId isn't optional

Comment: What is the result when you `print(snapshot)` also take a look at `firstTextField.text` that might be an optional and that might be the reason why you are always getting `false`

Comment: printing snapshot gets: Snap (following) null

Comment: text isn't optional

Comment: problem is with you query